# Put all code in one div class with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

How I can put this code into one div class .element?

```
var side_bar_html = "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[" + parseInt(gmarkers.length - 1) + "],\"click\");'>" + place.name + "</a><br>" + '<div class="raty" />' + "</br>";

$(side_bar_html).appendTo('#side_bar').filter('.raty').raty({
    score : place.rating,
    path : 'http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/img'
})
```

this code render HTML:

```
<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[0],"click");'>The Fort</a>
<br>
<div class="raty" style="cursor: pointer; width: 100px;"><img src="http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/img/star-on.png" alt="1" title="bad">&nbsp;<img src="http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/img/star-on.png" alt="2" title="poor">&nbsp;<img src="http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/img/star-on.png" alt="3" title="regular">&nbsp;<img src="http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/img/star-on.png" alt="4" title="good">&nbsp;<img src="http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/img/star-half.png" alt="5" title="gorgeous"><input type="hidden" name="score" value="4.5"></div>
```

I want to all this code put into DIV class .elemenat

How to do that?

do i need to write a function for that?

Comment: Which code you wan to put in div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this to append element in div.

```
var div="<div class='element'></div>";
$('.element').append(side_bar_html );
```

Comment: What is your `div` variable for?